# Default roles ticked when creating new login through SSMS GUI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, role, default-value

When creating a new login via the GUI:

In the *User Mapping* section, certain databases will have some roles pre-ticked in the Database Role Membership section.

What controls this behavior? It's different for each database.

[image: Pre-ticked boxes in Database Role Membership section]

Oddly, this does not occur when creating a database user via the GUI.

**Edit:** Adding *Script* code generated after filling in username and selecting *Map* on ADCData DB.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [testLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[ADCData], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
use [ADCData];
GO
CREATE USER [testLogin] FOR LOGIN [testLogin]
GO
USE [ADCData]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [testLogin]
GO
USE [ADCData]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [testLogin]
GO
```

Again, I'm not ticking these role membership boxes - they are pre-ticked once I select *Map* on the database.

**Edit II:** I'm not sure of the history of this DB - I'd estimate there's a 60% chance it's been restored from a backup. It also happens when adding **any** login - in the code example *testLogin* is not a login previously used.

**Edit III:** Above code was generated by clicking the *Script* button at the *Login - New* dialog. My issue is that the *db_datareader* and *db_datawriter* role options are ticked by default - I want to know what is determining that.

Also, I double-checked and there are no triggers at the server or db level.

[image: Script button in New Login dialog box]

**Edit IV:** My sincere appreciation to everyone working on this question. Unmodified *Guest* db user screenshot is below. No permissions are given, and CONNECT is revoked. I tried briefly granting CONNECT and seeing if that changed the UI, but it was still the same.

[image: guest user dialog box. No role memberships.]

Comment: I could not reproduce this in SQL 2019 CU15. I thought if you dropped the login and not the user, and try to add the same login this might happen. Was the database restored from a backup?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, where did your example script come from?...it does show it's adding the User to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles. If you're saying this is the script from the GUI when you click on the "User Mapping" section, how did you obtain it?...the Profiler? Outside of that, you should verify there's no Server or Database triggers that may be causing this behavior.

Comment: check if the guest user is a member of db_datareader and db_datawriter in that database